# Java String Deobfuscation

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, malware

I'm new to Java and was hoping someone could help me explain an issue. I am following [this blog post](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2022/04/anatomy-android-malware-dropper) that covers the reverse-engineering of a malicious Android APK file.

In the decompiled Java code, there is a string obfucation method that appears thousands of times in the code:

```
private static String $(int i, int i2, int i3) {
    char[] cArr = new char[i2 - i];
    for (int i4 = 0; i4 < i2 - i; i4++) {
        cArr[i4] = (char) ($[i + i4] ^ i3);
    }
    return new String(cArr);
}
```

Also in the code are calls that appear to use this method, such as `$(556, 664, 4277)`

I am having trouble deobfuscating the string. I know I can define a locally-scoped variable and use that to print out the decoded string, but I am not sure how that would look in Java. Can anyone provide an an example of how this would look?

I am certain that my attempts are incorrect. I am now motivated to actually learn Java, but I'd really like to understand what I'm doing wrong:

```
public static String $(int i, int i2, int i3) {
    char[] cArr = new char[i2 - i];
    for (int i4 = 0; i4 < i2 - i; i4++) {
        cArr[i4] = (char) ($[i + i4] ^ i3);
    }
    return new String(cArr);
}

var obfuscatedString = $(556, 664, 4277);
System.out.println(obfuscatedString);
```

Comment: ` System.out.println(cArr)` is a) unreachable, b) not a complete statement. Remove it.

Comment: How does `cArr[i4] = (char) ($[i + i4] ^ i3);`  compile? There is no array named `$`.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer There must be one, somewhere else, in code we haven't seen.

Comment: Suggestions to edit the question:  Show the variable `$`. How is it declared?  Is it a class (i.e., `static`) variable? Where is it declared? What does it contain?  Compile and run the code, showing actual output. Are you able to show a [complete but minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?    A minor edit: It looks like the code for the `$` method is duplicated. Delete one of them.

Comment: All, I apologize for the confusion. This was the code snippet as seen in the source (as decompiled by Jadx). It is clear now that there is missing information that is required before this can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be helpful to have a version of the code where the parameters and variables have better names that are easier to understand. The decompiler is just assigning meaningless names of `i`, `i2`, etc. to all the `int` variables.

```
private static String $(int start, int end, int xor) {
    int length = end - start;
    char[] chars = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        chars[i] = (char) ($[start + i] ^ xor);
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

I am making this a Community Wiki. If you feel the method can be made even more readable, feel free to contribute edits. I have introduced a temporary variable, `length`, but I left the name of the method as `$` and the external array of char that is being deobfuscated as `$` because those symbols are referenced externally and so would need to remain the same if the rewritten method were to replace the original one.